# Best way to extract data between several xml tags from a file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, string, stringbuffer

---

```
> <DOC>
> <Car> Zen </Car> 
> <Description> This is a bla bla model. which is a bla
> bla thisnf dsgs
> sdfsgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttttwqqqqqqqqq
> dsgdsdsssssssssssegsegsdgsdgsdsssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttt
> sdgssddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdddddddddwwww
> dgdssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsssssssssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwww
> gdgdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeeeeeeee
> gddsssssssssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeqqqqqqqqqqq
> gsdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssseqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
> dsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
> arrwerfkafjsdfsojfiosjfiosdfoisdoifjsdoifjiosdjfosdj</Description>
> <Year> 2015 </Year> <Color> Red </Color> 
> <Engine> afsdf </Engine>
> </DOC>
```

---Some more tags----

```
> <DOC>
> <Car> Zen1 </Car> <Description> This is the second text tag which is a
> bla bla thisnf dsgs
> sdfsgssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttttwqqqqqqqqq
> dsgdsdsssssssssssegsegsdgsdgsdsssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttt
> sdgssddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdddddddddwwww
> dgdssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsssssssssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwww
> gdgdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeeeeeeee
> gddsssssssssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeqqqqqqqqqqq
> gsdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssseqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
> dsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
> arrwerfkafjsdfsojfiosjfiosdfoisdoifjsdoifjiosdjfosdj</Description>
> <Year> 2015 </Year> <Color> Red </Color> <Engine> afsdf </Engine>
> </DOC>
```

---Some more tags----

I have several files, each file have many such tags within them.
What is the best way to extract the data between each of   and   tags?
This is my approach

```
> for (File file : files) { 
> System.out.println(file.getName());   
> if
> (file.isFile()) {         
> try {
>       BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));             >       String line; 
>       XContentBuilder builder = null;
>       StringBuffer sb = null; 
>       String descrption= null; 
>       String car =null;   
>       Boolean within_description = false; 
>           String Car= "";
>           while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
>               // System.out.println(line);
>               if (line.equals("<DOC>")) {
>                   builder = jsonBuilder();
>                   sb = new StringBuffer();
>                   continue;
>               } 
>               
>       
>               if (line.contains("<CAR>")) {
>                    
>                   String remove_front_space = line.replaceAll("<CAR>",
>                           "");
>                   car= remove_front_space .replaceAll("</CAR>",
>                           "").trim();
>                   builder = builder.startObject().field("CARR",
>                           car);
>                   continue;
>               }
>               if (line.equals("</DESCRIPTION>")) {
>                   within_description = false;
>                   continue;
>               }
>               if (within_description) {
>                   sb.append(line);
>                   continue;
>               }
>               if (line.equals("<DESCRIPTION>")) {
>                   within_description = true;
>                   continue;
>               }
>               if (line.equals("</DOC>")) {
>                   // JSONifying the string data
>                   text_toadd = sb.toString();
>                   builder = builder.field("text", text_toadd)
>                           .endObject();
>                   sb = null;
```

> ----Make database call and store CAR and DESCRIPTION information into Database.

```
>                 }     
>           bufferReader.close(); 
>           String json = builder.string(); 
>           System.out.println(json);
> 
>       } catch (IOException e) {           
>           e.printStackTrace();        
>       }
>   } }
```

Any suggestion would do.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, it's XML, not HTML. Then, don't reinvent the wheel. Use SAX or DOM parser to parse your XML file.

Comment: [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) is a great blog which contains an example for DOM parsing in Java.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for the link! But I am getting an "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." Because my documents don't have a parent root node. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @user1799214 The XML files you gave in your above post looked well-formed to me.  However, you could try adding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> to the start of the file and see if that works.  If not, then there are many possible reasons why your XML may not be well-formed.

Comment: I am new to XML and HTML but I have a question. Is it required to have a root element like 
<ROOT>    <A> some data </A> <B> some more data </B> <A> some more text </A> <B> text </B> </ROOT>
Can I still use SAX or DOM without <ROOT> tag and <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  tag?? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @user1799214 I just checked the example I gave above, and I found that you do not need the leading XML tag, but you do need a root element.  See below for my response and more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent post [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) which discusses how to use a DOM parser to extract an XML file into a tree.  One important point to keep in mind is that you **must** have a root element in your XML file.  Failure to do so will result in the following SAXParseException:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

If you don't have a root element, this exception is a bit misleading.  What is happening is that the parser assumes the first tag it hits is the root element.  When it encounters content outside of the **close** of this assumed root element, it rolls over and dies.  It should be clear that the parser fails because it is trying to build a tree, but without a root it has dangling tags which cannot be attached to anything.